# scroll with javascript for view firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want add vertical scroll for may div element.  I use `-webkit-scrollbar` CSS code but this method not working in firefox browser

I think only method for scrollbar in firefox browser is javascript method!
please help me for this code

```css
.news-box{
    width: 380px;
    height: 360px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    float: left;
    background: #fff;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.news-box-title{
    width: 340px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}
.news-box li{
    line-height: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    color: #5d5d5d;
}
.news-box li:nth-child(even){

    background: #f2f2f2;
}
.news-box li a {
    line-height: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="news-box">
        <div class="news-box-title"><span>news</span></div>
        <li>
            <a target="_blank"  href="" title="">text</a>
        </li>
     <li>
            <a target="_blank"  href="" title="">text</a>
        </li>
             <li>
            <a target="_blank"  href="" title="">text</a>
        </li>
             <li>
            <a target="_blank"  href="" title="">text</a>
        </li>
             <li>
            <a target="_blank"  href="" title="">text</a>
        </li>
             <li>
            <a target="_blank"  href="" title="">text</a>
        </li>

            </div>
```

Comment: firefox isn't `-webkit-` it is `-moz-` or *no prefix* - by the way, the code you posted has a) no -webkit-scrollbar, and b) a scrollbar

Comment: I think dont working scroll in firefox

Comment: can you add scroll to my code? without javascript? I dont want use defualt scroll

Comment: You already have `overflow-y: scroll;` and that's what you need to add a vertical scrollbar.

Comment: You need to use a js plugin to get cross browser styled scrollbars

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow:scroll;
```

example - [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smorris1900/pdrbfd6g/)

Comment: I know i want to create custom scrollbar